# php picture resize not working on image upload

Tags: php, image, forms, upload, resize

I'm trying to resize an image that's being uploaded on my php form. The picture is being saved but not resizing. Basically, everything is working fine except for the resizing of the image part. I put my code below.

html form with php for re sizing

```
<?php include "base.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 
Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Submit an Album</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
   if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

      include('SimpleImage.php');
      $image = new SimpleImage();
      $image->load($_FILES['albumCover']['tmp_name']);
      $image->resize(150,150);
      $image->output();
   } else {

?>

     <table>
        <tr>
        <td align="center">Submit an Album</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
     <table>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="submitAlbumForm.php" method="post">
        <tr>
          <td>Artist Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="artistName" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Album Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="albumName" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Release Date</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="releaseDate" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
        <tr>
          <td>Leak Date</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="leakDate" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Where It Leaked</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="whereItLeaked" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Album Cover</td>
          <td><input type="file" name="albumCover">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
   }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

submitAlbumForm.php, the php form for uploading form info to database

```
<?php
include "base.php";

//Setting up images directory
$target = "images/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['albumCover']['name']);

$albumCover=($_FILES['albumCover']['name']); 

//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO albums
            (artistName, albumName, releaseDate, leakDate, whereItLeaked, albumCover)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[artistName]',
            '$_POST[albumName]',
            '$_POST[releaseDate]',
            '$_POST[leakDate]',
            '$_POST[whereItLeaked]',
            '{$_FILES['albumCover']['name']}')";

 //Writes image to database
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `albums` VALUES ('albumCover')") ; 

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['albumCover']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives an error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
if($result){
    echo("<br>Thank you for submitting!");
} else{
    echo("<br>Sorry, something went wrong! Please try again!");
}
?>
```

SimpleImage.php, the script i'm using for resizing the image-

```
<?php

/*
* File: SimpleImage.php
* Author: Simon Jarvis
* Copyright: 2006 Simon Jarvis
* Date: 08/11/06
* Link: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php
*
* This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
* modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
* as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
* of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
*
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
* GNU General Public License for more details:
* http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*
*/

class SimpleImage {

   var $image;
   var $image_type;

   function load($filename) {

      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }
      if( $permissions != null) {

         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image);
      }
   }
   function getWidth() {

      return imagesx($this->image);
   }
   function getHeight() {

      return imagesy($this->image);
   }
   function resizeToHeight($height) {

      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }      

}
?>
```

I know I have a lot of security holes right now, and will be working on those soon! Thanks guys!

Comment: So.. You expect us to read all that? Where _exactly_ is it going wrong? That would be more helpfull ;)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a debugging service. You must ask a specific question related to programming, show us the **relevant** parts of your code (and not hundreds of lines), and someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't very clear haha, everything is working fine except the php piece in the html form, it's not actually resizing and saving the image before it's uploaded to my database.

Comment: Which of the code parts is submitAlbumForm.php?

Comment: What is the PHP error you get?

Comment: Submit album form is the part I labeled as 'php form for uploading form info to database'. Sorry, I'll go and rename everything properly

Comment: Do you want to save the image in the original size and then make a resized version of it on-the-fly? (Your code hints at this idea.) Or do you want to save the resized file instead of the original sized file? Or do you want to hold both an original-sized and a resized version of every uploaded image?

Comment: I was hoping to resize it and just save the resized image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see how the if block with `if( isset($_POST['submit']) )` ever gets hit and if it does then the image data would be directly output, which would not work since it is surrounded by HTML. A separate script that outputs the data of a resized image would be more appropriately handled by a separate script. (Perhaps one that takes GET params for the size?) If you are trying to save a resized copy of the image instead of the original-size image, then you should probably do that after `move_uploaded_file`. You could probably use `SimpleImage::save()` to do that. Maybe this would work:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['albumCover']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{ 
    require_once 'SimpleImage.php';
    $image = new SimpleImage();
    $image->load($target);
    $image->resize(150,150);
    $image->save($target); // Overwrites the image with a resized one

    // Tells you if its all ok 
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
} 
else ...
```

Comment: Great! I didn't check the code so I was lucky. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, your image resizing code is inside the `if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {` check on your form, but this code will never be run as the form submits to `submitAlbumForm.php` which is a different page entirely. I think you just need to move your resizing code into submitAlbumForm.php, probably inside the `if(move_uploaded_file(...)` block and change the paths as appropriate.

Comment: Right on, that's gotta be it.  Not only that, but he references `$_FILES['albumCover']['name']` on that page too, so he's pulling the whole image fresh from the request even if it had been resized and saved somewhere.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! Definitely helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can try my own program.
I do upload and store the data and images can be reduced in size that we can change.

i use php and xampp.
directory :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\phpyan\6_Database_2
6_Database_2 :
..images (dir)
..packages (dir)
..input_personal_info.php (file)

..images
   ..small(dir)
   ..more pict (file picture)
-----------------------------
..packages
   ..ClassDatabase.php 
   ..Personal.php
```

in the "images folder" there is a folder called "small"

notes :
*and in the package folder I keep the classes to function as a function of storing data and uploading image in small size*

input_personal_info.php

```
<?php
 include 'packages/ClassDatabase.php';
 include 'packages/Personal.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Input Personal Information</title>
  </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Personal Information</h1>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" name="frm_personal_info" method="post">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="First_Name"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Last_Name"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Date Birth</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Date_Birth"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td>
        <select name="Gender">
         <option value="">Gender...</option>
         <option value="Pria">Pria</option>
         <option value="Wanita">Wanita</option>
         <option value="Lainnya">Lain..</option>
        </select>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Photo Profile</td>
      <td><input type="file" name="Photo_Profile"></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>About</td>
      <td><textarea name="About" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea></td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
<?php
// connect with database
$connector = new ClassDatabase("localhost","root","","RawnayDB");
$connector->connect();
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // assign values on variabel
      $first_name = $_POST['First_Name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['Last_Name'];
    $date_birth = $_POST['Date_Birth'];
    $gender = $_POST['Gender'];
    $about = $_POST['About'];
    $dir = "images/";
    $dir2 = "images/small/";
    $photo_name = $_FILES['Photo_Profile']['name'];
    $photo_error = $_FILES['Photo_Profile']['error'];
    $photo_type = $_FILES['Photo_Profile']['type'];
    $photo_size = $_FILES['Photo_Profile']['size'];
    $photo_tmp = $_FILES['Photo_Profile']['tmp_name'];

    $personals = new Personal();

    // save file foto
    $personals->uploadPic($dir,$photo_name,$photo_tmp);
    // save pic small
    $personals->thumbPic($dir2,$photo_name);
    // save data
    $personals->savePersData($first_name,$last_name,$date_birth,$gender,$photo_name,$about);


 }
?>
```

packages/ClassDatabase.php

```
<?php
// class Database
class ClassDatabase{
  var $host;
  var $user;
  var $pswd;
  var $db;

  function ClassDatabase($host,$user,$pswd,$db){
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->pswd = $pswd;
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  function connect(){
  // Connection Test
    if(mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pswd))
    {mysql_select_db($this->db);} else {echo "Connection Failed";}

  }
}
?>
```

packages/Personal.php //> class

```
<?php
// class personal

class Personal{

  var $tabel = "personal";
  var $photo_original;
  var $photo_small;
  var $width;
  var $height;
  var $thumbWidth = 100;
  var $thumbHeight;

  function savePersData($fstnm,$lstnm,$dtbrth,$gndr,$photo_name,$about){
      $small = $this->photo_small;
      $original = $this->photo_original;
      $photo_name = "Pic".$fstnm;
      $query = "INSERT INTO $this->tabel VALUES('','$fstnm','$lstnm','$dtbrth','$gndr','$photo_name','$small','$original','$about');";
      if(mysql_query($query)){
        echo "<script>alert('penyimpanan sukses');</script>";
      }
  }

  function uploadPic($dir,$photo_name,$photo_tmp){
     is_uploaded_file($photo_tmp);
     $check = move_uploaded_file($photo_tmp,$dir.$photo_name);
     if($check){
     $this->photo_original=$dir.$photo_name;
     }
  }

  function thumbPic($dir2,$filename){
    $photo_original = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->photo_original);
    $this->width = imagesx($photo_original);
    $this->height = imagesy($photo_original);
    $this->thumbHeight = ($this->thumbWidth/$this->width)*$this->height;
    // resample picture
    $gbr_thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($this->thumbWidth,$this->thumbHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($gbr_thumb,$photo_original,0,0,0,0,$this->thumbWidth,$this->thumbHeight,$this->width,$this->height);
    // Save your directory
    $acak = rand(00000,999999);
    imagejpeg($gbr_thumb, $dir2."Small_Rawnay_Pic_".$acak.".jpeg");
    $this->photo_small = $dir2."Small_Rawnay_Pic_".$acak.".jpeg";
  }
}
?>
```